# Find $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ if $a+ia$ is a root of the equation $z^2+4z+b=0$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I managed to solve until $a=-2, b=8$ by expanding the conjugate roots and then comparing coefficients.

However, there is another pair of solution where $a=0,b=0$. What is the explanation for this second pair of solution?

Comment: If $a=0$, then based on the information it should have repeated root which is not possible with the coefficients given.

Comment: The equation has two roots $a\pm ia$ only when $a\not=0$ since if $a=0$, then $a+ia$ is real.

Comment: If $a+ai = a-ai$ then they are not *two* different roots.  They are one and the same root.  So if $a+ai = a-ai$ and $a+ai\in \mathbb R$ this we can *not* conclude $P(z) = (z -(a+ai))(z-(a-ai))$  we can only conclude that $(z-(a+ai)) = (z-(a-ai))$ *divides* $P(z)$.  And if $a+ai = 0$ then $(z-(0+0i)) = (z-(0-0i)) = z-0=z$ *does* divide $z^2 + 4z + b$.  But so does $(z-4)$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

If $w\in \mathbb C$ is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients then $\overline w$ is a root.  But that doesn't mean $\overline w$ is a *different* and second root.

If $w = \overline w$ (i.e. if $w \in \mathbb R$) then it is possible but $w$ and $\overline w = w$ are two representations of the same single root. (or it could be that $w$ is a double root.... but it *could* be a single root).

In other words the conjugate root theorem is trivial for real numbers.  As every real number is its own conjugate, then all the theorem states for real roots is.... If $w$ is a real root then... $w$ is a real root.

2)

If $u$ and $v$ are are two *different* roots, or if $u=v$ but $u$ is a double root, to a quadratic polynomial $z^2 + az + b$ then $(z-u)(z-v) = z^2 +az + b$.

But if $u$ is only one root and we don't know the other root ... we can't do anything.

....

So.....

If $a+ai$ is one root then $a-ai$ is a root.  And *IF* $a+ai \ne a-ai$ then, yes, we may conclude that $(z-(a+ai))(z-(a-ai)) = z^2 + 4z + b$ and we may conclude that $a=-2$ and $b=8$.

But if $a+ai = a-ai$ and is a *single* root, then the other root... is something else (although we can conclude the other root is real).

If we *do* try to solve this, $a+ai = a-ai \implies a=0$ and if the other root is $u$ the we have $(z-0)(z-u)= z^2 -uz + 0*u = z^2 +4z + b$ and thus $u=-4$ and $b = 0$.

.....

Or in other words.  If $w$ is one root we know that $z-w$ divides $P(z)= z^2 + 4z + b$.  ANd if $\overline w$ is *another* root we know $z-\overline w$ divides $P(z)$.  And so $(z-w)(z-\overline w)$ divides $P(z)$.  But as $P(z)=z^2 +4z + b$ is of degree $2$ and so is $(z-w)(z-\overline w)$ then $(z-w)(z-\overline w) = P(z)$.

But if $w$ is one *real* root then $\overline w = w$ and all we know is that $z- w = z-\overline w$ divides $P(z)= z^2 + 4z + b$  but that doesn't mean $(z-w)(z-\overline w) = (z-w)^2$ divides.  We only have *one* root, not two.

So if $a+ai= a-ai$ then $a = 0$ and $a+ai = 0$. and $z-0 = z$ divides $P(z)=z^2+4z + b$ so $z|b$ so $b = 0$.

If we knew the other root $u$ we'd know $z-u$ divides $z^2 + 4z +0$.  But we know that $\frac {z^2 + 4z+0}{z} = z+4$ we know that $z+4$ divides $P(z)$ and $P(z) = z(z+4)$ and the other root is $u = -4$... but that isn't what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since coefficient are real root will exist in Conjugate pairs
i.e if a(1+i ) is one of root then other is a(1-i ) only.
Now use sum of roots and product of roots 
a=-2 and b=8

The other solution is conditional if b=0 then the roots are real and equal both 0,0 as equation get reduced to $z^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that if $a(1+i)$ is a root, then $a(1-i)$ is also a root of the equation, care must be taken that $a(1+i)$ has non-zero imaginary part and is non-real. When $a=0$, the root is real and the result can't be applied.